# Using ResNet50 multiples times with different inputs (weights shared)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, tf.keras

I would like to use the same ResNet50 multiple times with different inputs, i.e. weights shared. Below is my coce but I'm getting the error message `AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'output'` for the line `resnet_x = resnet_x.output`.

What do I have to change to make it work?

```
from tensorflow.keras.applications.resnet50 import ResNet50
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input
from tensorflow.keras.layers import GlobalAveragePooling2D
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam

input_tensor_x = Input(shape=(96,96,3))
input_tensor_y = Input(shape=(96,96,3))
input_tensor_z = Input(shape=(96,96,3))

base_model = ResNet50(weights=None, include_top=False, input_shape=(96,96,3))
resnet_x = base_model(input_tensor_x)
resnet_x = resnet_x.output
resnet_x = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(resnet_x)
resnet_x = Dropout(0.5)(resnet_x)

resnet_y = base_model(input_tensor_y)
resnet_y = resnet_y.output
resnet_y = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(resnet_y)
resnet_y = Dropout(0.5)(resnet_y)

resnet_z = base_model(input_tensor_z)
resnet_y = resnet_y.output
resnet_y = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(resnet_y)
resnet_y = Dropout(0.5)(resnet_y)

merge_layer = tf.keras.layers.Concatenate()([resnet_x, resnet_y, resnet_z])

output_tensor = Dense(self.num_classes, activation='softmax')(merge_layer)

# instantiate and compile model
cnn_model = Model(inputs=[input_tensor_x, input_tensor_y, input_tensor_z], outputs=output_tensor)
opt = Adam()
cnn_model.compile(loss=categorical_crossentropy, optimizer=opt, metrics=['accuracy', tf.keras.metrics.AUC()])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simply removing the lines `resnet_XXX = resnet_XXX.output` does the job. pay attention to the name of the variables (below resnet_z layer)

```
input_tensor_x = Input(shape=(96,96,3))
input_tensor_y = Input(shape=(96,96,3))
input_tensor_z = Input(shape=(96,96,3))

base_model = ResNet50(weights=None, include_top=False, input_shape=(96,96,3))
resnet_x = base_model(input_tensor_x)
resnet_x = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(resnet_x)
resnet_x = Dropout(0.5)(resnet_x)

resnet_y = base_model(input_tensor_y)
resnet_y = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(resnet_y)
resnet_y = Dropout(0.5)(resnet_y)

resnet_z = base_model(input_tensor_z)
resnet_z = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(resnet_z)
resnet_z = Dropout(0.5)(resnet_z)

merge_layer = tf.keras.layers.Concatenate()([resnet_x, resnet_y, resnet_z])

output_tensor = Dense(10, activation='softmax')(merge_layer)

# instantiate and compile model
cnn_model = Model(inputs=[input_tensor_x, input_tensor_y, input_tensor_z], outputs=output_tensor)
opt = Adam()
cnn_model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=opt, metrics=['accuracy', tf.keras.metrics.AUC()])
```